# Software center claims that winetricks installed but it doesn't show up in apps

Tags: software-installation, wine, unity-dash

I installed Wine (meta-package) which also installed Winetricks, but when I search winetricks in the dash, it doesn't show up. The only thing that comes up is `uninstall wine software`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`winetricks` is not a GUI application.

It is not supposed to appear in Dash.

You can run `winetricks` in terminal.

Comment: It's definitively a GUI application, which has never prevented anything for not being in the dash or in any application menu.

Comment: This statement is wrong. Winetricks is just a script.

Comment: To the end user it doesn't matter, it's still a GUI to install stuff for wine.